# JavaFX 2 images location

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I have the following code and it will only load the image from where this class file is. I am using Ant and the classpath is set right. But the image cannot be load if it is in another folder which is on the classpath.

**new Image(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("logo.png"))**

Do I have to put images with class files?

Answer (score 2):

With this call you can load your image from the same package and the same JAR. If it is in a different JAR then it could be loaded with a different Classloader and you have problems. Therefore if you have a JAR file structure like:

```
com
   mypackage
       MyClass.class
       logo.png
```

then your call should work.

If you want to adress a different folder in your JAR then you could use absolute or relative paths

```
/com/logo.png
```

is absolute from your JAR - file root. And

```
test/logo.png
```

would be relative to your class file.

Just to be complete, this is your JAR file structure for my absolute and relative path examples:

```
com <dir>
   logo.png
   mypackage <dir>
       MyClass.class
       logo.png
       test <dir>
           logo.png
```